# Airflow - Experimental API returning 405s for some endpoints

Tags: airflow

I'm trying to set up my application to use Airflow's Experimental API. I'm using `apache-airflow==1.10.2`.

Using the config straight out of the box (no authentication enabled), I'm able to create DAG runs using the `POST /api/experimental/dags/<DAG_ID>/dag_runs` endpoint. However, when I try to use `GET /api/experimental/dags/<DAG_ID>/dag_runs` I get 405s.

I tried enabling authentication when I noticed that that GET endpoint is part of the `www_rbac` folder, but not part of the `www` file. To verify I was able to successfully setup authentication, I configured it for both the api and webserver.

```
[api]
authenticate = True
auth_backend = airflow.contrib.auth.backends.password_auth
```

and for the webserver:

```
[webserver]
# additional config omitted for brevity
authenticate = True
auth_backend = airflow.contrib.auth.backends.password_auth
```

I created a user using the airflow cli. Then, I was able to log into the webserver using those credentials. Problem is when I try to use that same credentials authenticating on the API, I'm still getting 405s.

Sample curl I'm using is:

```
curl -X GET \
  http://api_admin:password666@fakeHostName.com/api/experimental/dags/example_bash_operator/dag_runs \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache'
```

(Real curl has actual username, password, and hostname.)

Response body is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The method is not allowed for the requested URL.</p>
```

Curl for POST request that *does* work:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://api_admin:password666@fakeHostName.com/api/experimental/dags/example_bash_operator/dag_runs \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -d '{}'
```

Good news is that when I have authentication enabled and omit the username and password from the request, I get 401 - Unauthorized.

Has anybody been able to use the `GET` dag_run endpoint to work?

Answer (score 1):

That is a bug in `1.10.2` and has been fixed for `1.10.3` which will be released this week.

Till then you can use the rbac UI:

Enable the RBAC UI by modifying `airflow.cfg` file.

Under `[webserver]` section, change `rbac = False` to `rbac = True`

Note you will have to create a user as per https://airflow.apache.org/security.html?highlight=rbac#password