# 405 error when getting Airflow dag runs through rest api

Tags: airflow

I'm trying to use the airflow REST api (v1.10.2) but I'm having problems any time I try to query information about a specific dag.

Here's an example of the `latest_runs` endpoint working:

```
 ❯❯❯ curl -X GET http://192.168.99.100:30080/api/experimental/latest_runs
{
  "items": [
    {
      "dag_id": "test_dag",
      "dag_run_url": "/admin/airflow/graph?dag_id=test_dag&execution_date=2019-03-07+21%3A18%3A23.387031%2B00%3A00",
      "execution_date": "2019-03-07T21:18:23.387031+00:00",
      "start_date": "2019-03-07T21:18:23.683240+00:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, when I try to query `test_dag` I get an error:

```
 ❯❯❯ curl -X GET "http://192.168.99.100:30080/api/experimental/dags/test_dag/dag_runs"
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The method is not allowed for the requested URL.</p>
```

I've also tried looking in the source code and I found that there's a [state param](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/f4277cb32a3b75591ed6decb9f8d6c33f60986be/airflow/www/api/experimental/endpoints.py#L117) that can be used:

```
 ❯❯❯ curl -X GET "http://192.168.99.100:30080/api/experimental/dags/test_dag/dag_runs?state=success"
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The method is not allowed for the requested URL.</p>
```

but adding that in doesn't seem to help.

I find that triggering a DAG works:

```
 ❮❮❮ curl -X POST \
  http://192.168.99.100:30080/api/experimental/dags/test_dag/dag_runs \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{}'
{
  "message": "Created <DagRun test_dag @ 2019-03-07 22:31:18+00:00: manual__2019-03-07T22:31:18+00:00, externally triggered: True>"
}
```

Anyone have an idea why I can't query the status of a DAG and get a 405?

EDIT:
here's some more investigation. I tried using all of the possible methods, none of which succeed:

```
 4:21PM /Users/paymahn/solvvy/scheduler  ✘ 130 train.models ✭ ✱ ◼
 ❯❯❯ curl -X GET "http://192.168.99.100:30080/api/experimental/dags/test_dag/dag_runs"
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The method is not allowed for the requested URL.</p>
 4:21PM /Users/paymahn/solvvy/scheduler train.models ✭ ✱ ◼
 ❯❯❯ curl -X OPTIONS "http://192.168.99.100:30080/api/experimental/dags/test_dag/dag_runs"
 4:21PM /Users/paymahn/solvvy/scheduler train.models ✭ ✱ ◼
 ❯❯❯ curl -X TRACE "http://192.168.99.100:30080/api/experimental/dags/test_dag/dag_runs"
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The method is not allowed for the requested URL.</p>
 4:22PM /Users/paymahn/solvvy/scheduler train.models ✭ ✱ ◼
 ❯❯❯ curl -X PATCH "http://192.168.99.100:30080/api/experimental/dags/test_dag/dag_runs"
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The method is not allowed for the requested URL.</p>
 4:22PM /Users/paymahn/solvvy/scheduler train.models ✭ ✱ ◼
 ❯❯❯ curl -X DELETE "http://192.168.99.100:30080/api/experimental/dags/test_dag/dag_runs"
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The method is not allowed for the requested URL.</p>
 4:22PM /Users/paymahn/solvvy/scheduler train.models ✭ ✱ ◼
 ❯❯❯ curl -X HEAD "http://192.168.99.100:30080/api/experimental/dags/test_dag/dag_runs"
Warning: Setting custom HTTP method to HEAD with -X/--request may not work the
Warning: way you want. Consider using -I/--head instead.
curl: (18) transfer closed with 178 bytes remaining to read
 4:22PM /Users/paymahn/solvvy/scheduler  ✘ 18 train.models ✭ ✱ ◼
 ❯❯❯ curl -X PUT "http://192.168.99.100:30080/api/experimental/dags/test_dag/dag_runs"
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The method is not allowed for the requested URL.</p>
 4:22PM /Users/paymahn/solvvy/scheduler train.models ✭ ✱ ◼
 ❯❯❯ curl -X POST "http://192.168.99.100:30080/api/experimental/dags/test_dag/dag_runs"
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.</p>
```

Comment: Looks like this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54834097/airflow-experimental-api-returning-405s-for-some-endpoints

Comment: Made an issue with Airflow on JIRA: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-4043

Comment: have enable the authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that this endpoint is only enabled in 1.10.2 in the RBAC UI mode: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-4043?focusedCommentId=16787946&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-16787946.